# Storelocator and external data

Tags: maps

I have a piece of code that queries a distributors website to generate a list of stockists for our product, this generated a page with XML data on it. I want to use this information in a storelocator script to generate a map of stockists.

My question is, is there a way of importing the results from this page into the storelocator script, or would i use the code for the storelocator script inside my distributor script (the one that generates the xml)

Rob